# How do I serve two ports in Docker bounded to one?

Tags: docker

Let's suppose I have a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
...
EXPOSE 5000
...
CMD ["myserver", "--port", "5000"]
```

So if I want this container to serve port `80` for example, I would run it like this:

```
docker run -p 80:5000 ...
```

What do I need to do if I want this container to serve two different ports (for example, `80` and `88`) as one bounded to `5000`? I tried this without any success:

```
docker run -p 80,88:5000 ...
```

And is it legal what I want to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the use case but you can run it like this

`docker run -p 80:5000 -p 88:5000 ...`